# Calculating a complex definite improper integral: $I= \int_{0}^\infty x^{it}\,\mathrm{e}^{-ax}\, dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration

Does anyone know how to find the value of this integral:

$$I= \int_{0}^\infty x^{it}\,\mathrm{e}^{-ax}\, dx,$$

where $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and $t$, $a$ are real.

Please give me a hint.

Thank you.

Comment: Is $a$ also a real number?

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: For a general treatment of these types of integrals, you may be interested in learning about the Bilateral Laplace Transform: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Bilateral_Laplace_transform

Comment: If $a$ is real, then this integral does not converge, as $\lvert x^{it}\rvert=1$.

Comment: If $a>0$ (or Re$\,a>0$), then this integral would make sense if the limits were $\int_0^\infty$.

Comment: Here $a$ is real.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis, you are right, the limit is from 0 to $\infty$. So I corrected that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Let's start from the beginning. Do case $t=0$ easy. Then induction continuously. Easy to show $I=$ $$-\frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{3 \pi  t}{2}} \left(e^{2 \pi  t}-1\right)
   (\text{sgn}(a)+i) \left(-a^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i t}{2}} \Gamma (i
   t+1)$$

Comment: Is it possible to elaborate little bit of how you come up with the result ? Did you use integration by parts ?

Comment: Maybe. It is a good exercise.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
The integration is, indeed, $\ds{\sf\mbox{quite simple}}$ and it can be exppressed in terms of the $\ds{\sf Gamma}$ $\ds{\Gamma}$ function:

> \begin{align}&\overbrace{\color{#66f}{\large%
> \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\ic t}\expo{-ax}\,\dd x}}
> ^{\ds{\dsc{ax}\ \mapsto\ \dsc{x}}}\ =\
> a^{-1 - \ic t}\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\ic t}\expo{-x}\,\dd x}
> ^{\dsc{\Gamma\pars{\ic t + 1}}}\ =\
> \color{#66f}{\large a^{-1 - \ic t}\ \Gamma\pars{\ic t + 1}}
> \end{align}